# Are Creative Commons licenses enforceable in the event of a breach?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons, enforcement

**Scenario:**

I am building a website with my business partner. This website is going to contain information that we do not want to be reused. To do this I am going to release it under a creative commons license.

**Question:**

In the event someone uses our content without our permission, would I be able to take action against this person?

- If yes, to what extent?
- If no, why not?

Comment: You "do not want [the information] to be reused", but you "release it under a creative commons license"? Aren’t you *enabling* reuse by that in the first place?

Comment: Do you mean "reused commercially" or "reused in a derived form" instead of "reused"? You're *enabling* reuse with a CC license. Compare, "I do not want my relatives to visit me, so I sent them a letter with my home address and an open invitation to visit any time they like." Your stated objective and your actual behavior are completely at odds; are you sure your wording is correct here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there have been several cases where violations of a CC licence have been taken to court, and the rights holders have won. [Wikipedia lists just a few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Legal_aspects).

Note that the Creative Commons organisation would not be a legal party if this happened to you, and you would have to cover all of your own legal costs.